# Linq-To-SQL text search with the .Contains method

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq-to-sql, case-insensitive

I have a table, where I need to do a case insensitive search on a text field.

If I run this query in LinqPad directly on my database, it works as expected

```
Table.Where(tbl => tbl.Title.Contains("StringWithAnyCase"))
// also, adding in the same constraints I'm using in my repository works in LinqPad
// Table.Where(tbl => tbl.Title.Contains("StringWithAnyCase") && tbl.IsActive == true)
```

In my application, I've got a repository which exposes IQueryable objects which does some initial filtering and it looks like this

```
var dc = new MyDataContext();

public IQueryable<Table> GetAllTables()
{
    var ret = dc.Tables.Where(t => t.IsActive == true);
    return ret;
}
```

In the controller (its an MVC app) I use code like this in an attempt to mimic the LinqPad query:

```
var rpo = new RepositoryOfTable();
var tables = rpo.GetAllTables();
// for some reason, this does a CASE SENSITIVE search which is NOT what I want.
tables = tables.Where(tbl => tbl.Title.Contains("StringWithAnyCase");
return View(tables);
```

The column is defined as an `nvarchar(50)` in SQL Server 2008.

** update **

I had a partial class (for one of my Entities from Linq-To-SQL) with an IQueryable property, but somehow returning an IQueryable from an EntitySet caused my later queries to behave in an IEnumerable (read Linq-To-Objects) way even though they were acting on IQueryable types.

Comment: In between rpo.GetAllTables(); and tables.Where(...); you aren't doing anything else with it?

Comment: **EDIT:** Think it is a duplicate question. Check out this SO [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql). HTH

Comment: There is another method (for additional filtering) but they are all `IQueryable<Table>` I'm NOT doing any converting ToList or IEnumerable.