# Linq performing case insensitive comparison

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I want user object only when exact password along with case matches. However this query fetches result even when case for password is not same:

```
db.Users.Where(u => u.Username.ToLower() == username.ToLower() &&
                        u.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

What am I missing?

Comment: remove the .ToLower() obviously?

Comment: @Rob: `ToLower` is used on the username, not on the password.

Comment: Can you provide input and output data

Comment: @FredrikMörk wow seriously im getting blind  :D

Comment: Looks good to me - your problem is probably somewhere else. BTW, you could use `string.Equals` with `StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` for comparing user name case-insensitively, to avoid creating a pair of new `string` objects for each iteration of the LINQ loop.

Comment: My database has username: admin and password: Admin and if I provide user: admin and password: AdMiN it still works.

Comment: I know this is off-top, but what about hashing passwords?

Comment: @Rob: such details are surprisingly easy to overlook. I do it all the time.

Comment: If your database does not perform case sensitive comparison you might wanna look at the generated SQL

Comment: @Hohhi - agreed, hash the passwords and the string comparison issue disappears as a pleasant side-effect.

Comment: @Ian: You are trying to change the whole point of the question. What if this is not about password and something else? Please provide solution to my original question. See my title is 'Linq performing case insensitive comparison' and not how  to deal with passwords.

Comment: I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Simplest way is to do the username matching in the DB under it's case-insensitve rules and the password matching in .NET under its case-sensitive rules:

```
db.Users.Where(u => u.Username == username).ToList().Where(u => u.Password == password).FirstOrDefault();
```

The `ToList()` moves from db-based LINQ to object-based LINQ, and since there would only be one matching case anyway, the performance impact of doing so is negligible.

Still has the problem of storing a password in a database though!

Comment: Your solution looked the most sane to me.

Comment: There's something a bit unsatisfying in doing two types of LINQ filtering, but it should hopefully do the trick.

Comment: Yes there will be a negligible performance hit but it should be OK.

Comment: Exactly. Developer time matters too, and you've got bigger fish to fry than that little quibble (like the fact that you've got passwords stored in your database!).

Comment: It is not about performance, it is philosophically wrong. Coding is about writing down the rules of the world around us. If someone would verify this thing filtering twice, what would you say about such person?

Comment: @Hohhi: Then what do you want me to do? Imagine this is not about passwords and something else? Do you want me to hash every single string column in my database? I am using EF 4.1 Code First and Sql Server Compact Edition. EF code first has problems when you change model whole database gets recreated from scratch i.e dropped and recreated. Do you want me to keep changing collation like this everytime model gets changed and database is dropped and recreated? The collation thing is good for EF 4.0 general but not code first and hashing is not at all an option for anything other than passwords.

Comment: It is not philosophically wrong. It is to my mind æsthetically unpleasant to filter twice. However, we're filtering once by one set of rules and once by another; philosophically it's perfect, as the "rules of the world" in this case have two different filtering cases with slightly different rules.

Comment: @Jaggu, I do not want you to do anything, I just say it is not right and this is not the way it should be done IMHO

Comment: @Hohhi: Can you give me an alternate solution better than Jon?

Comment: @Jaggu, this code says: find me a list of users with UserName equal to param which is already wrong. It should say: find the user with UserName and may be even throw if there are two of them. You are authenticating ONE user. What kind of lists are we talking about? Do you get my point?

Comment: @Hohhi: Yes I get, but did you read my previous comment? "Can you give me a better solution that what Jon gave?"

Comment: @Jaggu, I'd write the next way:         var user = users.Single(u => u.UserName == username);
            if (user == null)
                throw new ArgumentException("No such user");
            Console.WriteLine(user.Password==password);

Comment: @Hohhi: Ok, more lines of code but basically you are also doing a Linq to Object only but I do get your point of philisophy and business rules and stuff. Good.

Comment: @Hohhi after you fix the bug (`Single` will throw where the desired result is a null), the test is essentially the same as what I have above.

Comment: var user = users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.UserName == username); if (user == null) throw new ArgumentException("No such user"); Console.WriteLine(user.Password==password);

Answer (score 3):

If the database is configured as case-insensitive, then you *cannot* get it to do a case-sensitive comparison on the password (unless you resort to [TSQL tricks](http://vyaskn.tripod.com/case_sensitive_search_in_sql_server.htm)). However! You ***should not be storing*** a password - you should be storing a salted hash (ideally salted per user). And the hash (as a blob) should be fine to compare this way.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
db.Users.Where(u => string.Compare(u.Username, username, System.StringComparison.OrdinalIngoreCase) == 0 &&
                    string.Compare(u.Password, password) == 0).FirstOrDefault();
```

Because this is being executed in the SQL you can't use the .NET/Linq comparison methods.

Comment: @Jaggu - now that is odd. Try brackets around the `string.Compare()`?

Comment: doesn't help. I am using EF 4.1 code first. Can that be a issue?

Comment: @Jaggu - Don't know, sorry. The only other thing is to explicitly set comparison type on the `password` check to `Ordinal`.

Comment: I found this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Answer (score 1):

Change the collation of the `Password` column in your `Users` table to use a case-sensitive collation such as Latin1_General_CS_AS.

Or, as others have commented, consider changing your solution to store hashes of the passwords instead (e.g. an SHA1 hash) and compare hashed values rather than plaintext passwords.

Comment: This table is created by code first and not me and sadly it has all nvarchar types. Code first has problems of dropping and recreating everything once your model changes so I need to do this everytime which is not good for me.

Comment: Thanks but couldn't find the collation you are talking about on this list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174596%28v=SQL.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

What is the database type of the password and what **collation** sequence are you using?

It it's the VARCHAR and you use case-insensitive collation, the behavior you describe is exactly what would be expected.

Default collation sequences for some databases may be case-insensitive (e.g. take a look at [SQL SERVER – Collate – Case Sensitive SQL Query Search](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/04/30/case-sensitive-sql-query-search/)), so you might be using case-insensitive collation without even knowing it. Obviously, you'll need to change the collation to get the correct results.

Answer (score 0):

If `u.Password` and `password` are of string type, then your code should work as expected.

Comment: It is not working. I am using Entity Framework 4.1 code first. No matter if I input admin or Admin, both way works and I get result

Answer (score 0):

try altering your column like this:

```
alter table [Users] alter column [password] nvarchar(100) collate Chinese_PRC_CS_AI
```