# Entity Framework and Case Sensitive String Search

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0, case-sensitive

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

See image below can you help why it is getting user record. If I am not wrong entity framework is case sensative I am passing value with small letter but it is still fetching record.
Why it is fetching record? :(

[image]

Comment: Please tell me the data in the screenshot is mock data and you didn't just post this poor guy's email (and a password) to SO...

Comment: this is sample data its not real email and even not correct password

Comment: OK, cool, thanks!  Always a good thing to note.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on the way you are fetching the record? Could you send us this piece of code?

Comment: Dup: [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison). I don't understant negative votes for this question. Some one can explain it!

Comment: User user = new ForeverWordsDBEntities().Users.Include("Country").Where(x => x.LoginId.ToLower().Trim() == LoginId.ToLower().Trim() && x.Password == Password && x.IsDisabled == false).SingleOrDefault();

Answer (score 5):

Is it possible that the database that you are querying is using a [case-insensitive coallation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx)? In that case, SQL Server itself, not EF, would be ignoring case.