# Checking if usernames exists, case-sensitive

Tags: c#, string, entity-framework, equals

```
public bool CheckUsername(string username)
{
    bool exists=false;

    var query =
        from t in db.Coaches
        where String.Equals(t.user_name,username)
        select t;


    List<Coach> coaches = query.ToList();
    if (coaches.Count!=0)
    {
        exists = true;
    }
    else
    {
        exists = false;
    }
    return exists;
}
```

This is my function. If for example the username `james` exists I want the users to still be able to create another user with username `James`, `JAMES`, ... etc for as far as I know `String.equals()` is case-sensitive but my function does not work. Any idea why this isn't working? I tried using compare but this does not work because it returns an int.

Comment: "my function does not work" doesn't tell us anything. Additionally, the second half of your code is equivalent to `return query.Any();`. Indeed, your whole method could be converted to `return db.Coaches.Any(t => t.user_name == username);`

Comment: I'm working with the entity framework. db is my context.

Comment: @JonSkeet actually it works , but it does not give back what I want. the comparison is invalid. I want that "james" != "James"

Comment: If it doesn't do what you want, then it *doesn't* work - but you haven't clearly described what *does* happen.

Comment: assuming "db" is EF, here's explanation how to do it:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm sorry for the misunderstanding, in the future I will describe my problems better.

Comment: @Visar Thank you , that might solve my issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`String.equals()` is case sensitive, but EF will translate that into SQL, which may not be case-sensitive depending on the collation of that column (or your database if the column does not have a collation specified).

You can solve this on the server side by setting the collation of that column to be case-sensitive

```
ALTER TABLE Coaches
ALTER COLUMN user_name VARCHAR(20)  // or whatever the size of your username column is
COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS
```

Or on the client side by pulling back all records that match a case-insensitive search and then filtering in Linq-To-Objects:

```
var query =
    from t in db.Coaches
    where String.Equals(t.user_name,username)
    select t;

// use `AsEnumerable()` to change to linq-to-objects
exists = query.AsEnumerable()
              .Any(i ==> i.user_name == username);
```

So long as you don't have thousands of users with the same username in different casing you shouldn't have too big of an impact by filtering in linq-to-objects.

Note that changing the collation of the column will affect *any* query that filters or sorts on `username`, so do plenty of testing in a separate environment before making that change.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that while String.Equals may be generally case-sensitive, the db is set to not be case sensitive in its queries. You may need to modify the database to set the field as case-sensitive.

Answer (score 0):

You have a spelling issue. Change the following:

```
excists = true;
```

To

```
exists = true;
```

Comment: unfortunately this mistake is not made in my real code, thanks for clearing that up

Comment: I was wondering why intellisense wasn't picking that up for you. :)