# == by default is case insensitive in c# linq

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, linq

I can't understand why:

In db I have record in Members table with Name = "Bob"

```
var a = await repository.Members.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.Name == "BOB"); //is true (Entity Framework Core)

var c = repository.Members.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name == "BOB"); //is true (LINQ)

var b = "Bob" == "BOB"; //is false
```

Comment: It's not "in LINQ" - it's "in the specific LINQ provider you're using, against the specific database you're using".

Comment: Possible duplicate of [linq to entities case sensitive comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: It's a SQL comparison, not LINQ. Sensitivity is controlled by the column's collation.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with LINQ. LINQ is just an abstraction mechanism allowing you to query different datasources using the same syntax. If you are using MSSQL by default it will have `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` collation which is case insensitive (Notice the `CI` in the name). So when your LINQ query gets translated to SQL (`select * from Members where Name = 'BOB'`) and run it will return results. So basically you might need to [`change the collation`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179254.aspx) of your SQL server database to one that is case sensitive if you want to perform case sensitive lookups with it.

Comment: Just as a side note, as per the flagged duplicate question, changing the collation of the column queried against should suffice, instead of changing collation of whole db.