# Why Receiving Null through LINQ?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, api

why part 2 is returning null.

the strange part is that if i search by string type then null returns, but if i search by integer type or bool type. then i get brand object.

**Part 1**

```
//....     OK code
                 public static Brand GetBrand(string name)
                {
                    DataContext db = new DataContext();
                    using (db)
                    {
                        Brand b = (from v in db.Brands
                                   where v.Name == name
                                   select v).FirstOrDefault();
                        return b;
                    }
                }




               [HttpGet]
               public IHttpActionResult Get(string name)
               {
                   Brand b = MobileHandler.GetBrand(name);
                   return Ok(b);
               }
```

**Part 2**

```
//.....   Return null
       public static List<Brand> GetBrands()
            {
                DataContext db = new DataContext();
                using (db)
                {
                    return db.Brands.ToList();
                }
            }

           [HttpGet]
           public IHttpActionResult Get(string name)
           {
               return Ok((from v in MobileHandler.GetBrands()
                          where v.Name == name
                          select v).FirstOrDefault());
           }
```

But I get the following error:

```
<Brand xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/DataLayer.MobileMgt" i:nil="true"/>
```

Comment: Depends what `MobileHandler.GetBrand` is doing. You're obviously searching for a brand which doesn't exist. In fact, your code explicitly expects no matches to be found, since it uses `FirstOrDefault()` rather than `First()`

Comment: show implementation of GetBrand & GetBrands and make sure brand you are searching exists.

Comment: Yes i have confirmed that brand exists

Comment: what is type for V.Name?? , As V.Name == name will compare type and value both, try using V.Name.Equals(name) if you care about only value.

Comment: still returns null. and type is string

Comment: the strange part is that only with string type i am having this issue, not with other types like int and bool

Comment: First()  returns error.   "Sequence contains no elements"   although i am getting brand name through first portion of my code.  #Rob

Comment: Can you give us what string are you using? There might be some special characters that are compared differently in SQL and in .NET . Did you try different strings?

Comment: No code part returns the brand name. There is only code returning a brand by name. What are you talking about?

Comment: http://localhost:28906/services/brand?name=apple

Comment: Be careful about upper/lower case comparisons. Make sure your character cases are same or use case-insensitive comparison.

Comment: #Sir Rufo     "I know no code is returning brand name. i am returning Brand object.  the problem is when i search by brand name. then it returns null but if i search by integer Id then i get Brand object"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is issue of case-sensitive comparison. This is indicated by your code working for `ints` and `bools` and not strings and by a fact that brand name is "**A**pple" not "**a**pple"

[Entity Framework uses case comparison settings on the SQL server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison), which is usually set to be case-insensitive. In your case then "Apple" is equals to "apple". This is the first case.

But .NET uses case-sensitive comparison, which is the second case. So "apple" wont be equal to "Apple". To fix this instead of `v.Name == name` use `v.Name.Equals(name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`.