# Entity Framework Case Sensitive Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, case-sensitive

I have a table that named `Post` which has a column named `key`:

```
  Id | Key | Title
 --------------------
   1 | WM  | First
 --------------------
   2 | wm  | Second
```

As you can see the first `key` value of a `Post` is `WM` (Uppercase) and the second `key` value is `wm` (lowercase).

When I execute the query with following code:

```
var post = await _posts.Where(o => o.Key == key).Select(o => new
    {
        id = o.Id,
        title = o.Title
    }).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

I pass the `key` with a value (wm and WM) but get one result. The second one (wm).

I've searched for the solution and found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)
and this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison/29866328#29866328). After I tried to use answer and implement `[CaseSensitive]` data annotation when I search for `wm` I get back the first post and when I search for `WM` I get `null`.
How can I solve this and get an adequate post with key?

**Update:**
Generated SQL Query:

```
   SELECT [Limit1].[C1]    AS [C1],
       [Limit1].[Id]    AS [Id],
       [Limit1].[Title] AS [Title]
FROM   (SELECT TOP (2) [Extent1].[Id]    AS [Id],
                       [Extent1].[Title] AS [Title],
                       1                 AS [C1]
        FROM   [dbo].[Posts] AS [Extent1]
        WHERE  ([Extent1].[Key] = 'wm' /* @p__linq__0 */)
                OR (([Extent1].[Key] IS NULL)
                    AND ('wm' /* @p__linq__0 */ IS NULL))) AS [Limit1]
```

Comment: Did you check to make sure your DB column was setup with the correct collation?  Personally I'd stick to doing `.Where(o => o.Key == key).AsEnumerable().Where(o => o.Key == key)`.

Comment: Check in your database what is the type of your `Key` column.

Comment: @ m.rogalski string

Comment: Why the SQL tag? (I see no SQL above.)

Comment: @juharr yes, I try this code but my code result doesn't change.

Comment: If you query the database directly (through Management Studio) and do `select * FROM TABLE WHERE Key = 'WM'`, what rows are returned (i.e does it return just `WM` or also `wm`)?

Comment: @mjwills No, it return post that `key = wm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I Solve this issue with same change:

1. change `Key` data type to `varchar`
2. and execute SQL Query with `SqlQuery<T>`:

   ```
   var post = await _uow.Database
               .SqlQuery<PostUrlDto>(
                   "SELECT Id , Title FROM Posts WHERE [Key] = @postkey COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CS_AS",
                   new SqlParameter("postkey", postkey)).SingleOrDefaultAsync()
   ```

Comment: Can't believe that this helps. You use a case-sensitive collation (CS)..

Comment: Case sensitive is what he / she wants @GertArnold .

Comment: Hmm, probably. The problem description isn't the clearest I ever saw.