# GroupBy isn't working correct on IQueryable

Tags: c#, entity-framework, group-by, iqueryable

I have class :

```
class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsMain { get; set; }
}
```

I'm getting data from DB using `GroupBy`:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

I have some data in DB:

```
IsMain = true, Name = "entity"  
IsMain = false, Name = "entity"
IsMain = true, Name = "Entity"
```

I'm using grouped entities like this:

```
 foreach (var entity in grouppedEntitiesByName)
    {
        var mainEntity = entity.Single(a => a.IsMain);
    }
```

Here I'm getting `Sequence contains more than one matching element` exception. Grouped entities has one key `entity` and three items:

```
  IsMain = true, Name = "entity"  
    IsMain = false, Name = "entity"
    IsMain = true, Name = "Entity"
```

Then I tried this:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().ToList().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

Here grouped entities has two key:
`entity` and `Entity`
Why group by is working incorrect in `IQueryable` and how to fix this?
(I'm using EF)

Comment: What result do you want exactly?

Comment: grouppedEntitiesByName should have two keys 'entity' and 'Entity'. First item which key is 'entity' should have two entity with IsMain = true and IsMain = false (each name is 'entity'). Second item which key is 'Entity' should have one entity with name 'Entity' and IsMain = true

Comment: Possible duplicate [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3843060/linq-to-entities-case-sensitive-comparison)

Comment: Can it be related to teh DB you are using? The only difference in the name is the capital E, so when it is grouped by DB ignoring case, it is still one group. In the list example it is pulled in memory first and the groupby is done in code. Maybe for testing purpose change name to Entity2..

Comment: I'm using SQL Server. I tried execute group by query with SQL Server Management 
 studio, it seems SQL Server doesn't take care of about lower and upper case

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default SQL Server has a a case insentive collation. EF will issue SQL statement, therefore the grouping result will be affected by your database settings.

If you need to group case sensitive, you need to do it by hand, for example by adding a new column with a case insensitive key, this way you are still using the database. Another option which will partially run in memory would be to use LINQ to perform the grouping with a custom sorter.

Answer (score 0):

It's because IEnumerable `GroupBy` is querying data from in-memory collection while IQueryable `GroupBy` query from out-memory collection. (source: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/a20beb/ienumerable-vs-iqueryable-in-linq/)

In you example

IQueryable:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

the statement is translated to sql query - `select whatever from Entity group by Name` which is a case insensitive group by.

IEunumerable:

```
var grouppedEntitiesByName = context.GetEntities<Entity>().ToList().GroupBy(en => en.Name);
```

The `ToList()` part loads the data in to memory and your `GroupBy` now is IEnumerable.GroupBy which is case sensitive.