# How can I get .ToUpper() (or the equivalent) to work when using .Contains() in Linq to Sql?

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql, case-insensitive

This code:

```
keyword = 's';
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = 
        (from m in members
         where m.ScreenName.ToUpper().Contains(keyword.ToUpper())
         select m).AsEnumerable();
```

Only returns records that have an uppercase 'S' in the `ScreenName`. Why is `m.ScreenName.ToUpper()` being ignored? How do I convert `m.ScreenName` to uppercase so I can perform case-insensetive checks?

## Edit

This is not a duplicate. I attempted the solution in the proposed duplicate:

```
IEnumerable<Member> searchResults = 
       (from m in members
        where m.ScreenName.Contains(keyword, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
        select m).AsEnumerable();
```

This failed. `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is not a valid parameter for .Contains().

Comment: possible duplicate of [Case insensitive string compare in LINQ-to-SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql)

Comment: @BlueRaja and @Danny - Thanks for the link. This is not a duplicate. That method is used on string.equals. I am using the .Contains() method. Please see edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way (AFAIK) to specify case sensitivity/insensitivity explicitly via Linq-to-SQL.

I would recommend modifying your database schema to use a case-insensitive collation on the column(s) you're searching.

SQL Server collation settings control things like case sensitivity, accent sensitivity (is 'cafe' the same as 'café' ?), and the rules used to perform string comparison and sorting.

Collations are selected from a list built in to SQL Server, and most of them will be called something like SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI

The last two pairs of characters are the important bit - CI_AI means case-insensitive, accent-insensitive. I suspect you'll find the the collation on the ScreenName column is set to something like CS_AI or CS_AS. Change this, and your query should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIR string comparison in SQL is case insensitive itself.

Comment: Then why am I getting case sensitive results?

Comment: Probably It's because of `collation` you set in your DB.

Comment: I am finding this to be a bit frusterating. I am wondering how to make .ToUpper() work correctly. If .ToUpper() is not an option in this case then I am looking for an equivalent solution. I have not set a collation value in the database. I don't know what collation does. If it is the case that collation has been set then I am probably stuck with it that way. So, is there a way to use `.Contains()` in a case-insensitive way?

Comment: Look at this page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx and see your DB's collation , then you may find out the issue.

Comment: How does this page help me get `.Contains()` and `.ToUpper()` to work correctly?

Comment: The problem has nothing to do with `.Contains`, the actual query is being done in the database and it's the database query that is being case sensitive due to collation. One test would be: If you use SQL Server Management Studio, are queries you run in it case sensitive?