# How can I search a strongly typed list for a string?

Tags: .net, vb.net, list, collections

How can I "search" through a strongly typed list for a string?

I am attempting .Contains(TheString), however it errors stating Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'o7thCrawler.Typing.ImportantTyping'

Here is the code:

```
Public Class LinkTyping
    Public Property Url As String
    Public Property Title As String
    Public Property Content As String
End Class

If Not (_InternalUrls.Contains(_Url & _Link)) Then
    _InternalUrls.Add(New Typing.LinkTyping() With {
                                                          .Url = _Url & _Link,
                                                          .Content = Item.Value,
                                                          .Title = If(Item.Attribute("title") IsNot Nothing,
                                                                      Item.Attribute("title").Value,
                                                                      Nothing)
                                                      })
End If
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to shoe-horn 2 types into the same list...

What type is `InternalUrls`?

This:

```
If Not (_InternalUrls.Contains(_Url & _Link)) Then
```

Implies it's an `IList(Of String)`

but this:

```
_InternalUrls.Add(New Typing.LinkTyping() With {
```

Then tries to add a new instance of your LinkTyping class to it...

How about something like...

Make `InternalURLs` be a `List(Of LinkTyping)`

Then

```
Dim MyUrl = String.Format("{0}{1}", _Url, _Link)
If Not InternalURLs.Any(function(x) x.Url = MyUrl) Then
    InternalURLs.Add(New Typing.LinkTyping() With {<Blah>})

End If
```

NB: The solution above assumes the URLs are going to be the same case for the purposes of matching (as does your example, assuming no overloaded comparison operator) - you may want to use a case-insensitive compare...

```
If Not InternalURLs.Any(function(x) String.Equals(x.Url, MyUrl, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)) Then
```

Comment: InternalUrls = List(Of Typing.LinkTyping)

Comment: @o7thWebDesign Are you implementing a custom comparator for your LinkTyping class - for use in the `.Contains`? How did the code above work for you?

Comment: Worked good.  it caught all the potential duplications.  I used the .Any, as I already force everything .ToLower() prior to this.

Comment: I can't vote up yet, need 2 more points LOL.  But I did accept this answer as begin it

Comment: @o7thWebDesign Understood - be a little careful when forcing to Upper or Lower to do a comparison - It can [cause problems](http://stackoverflow.com/a/841342/156755)... If you've got to do it, use Upper in preference to Lower.

Answer (score 1):

Assume _InternalUrls is a List, then the Contains method will use your objects implementation of Equals for deciding if an object is already in a collection. So one option would be to overload Equals for you class.

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3.aspx)

Comment: How would I do that?   Yes, _InternalUrls is the list in question., a List(Of Typing.LinkTyping) to be precise.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually pretty simple to do with a lambda expression:

```
If _InternalUrls.Any(Function(l) l.Url = _Url) Then
    ' Do Add Logic Here
```

You'll need to have the following at the top:

```
Imports System.Linq
```

(Changed the FirstOrDefault to use Any)