# Linq query return 1 item instead of all

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am using the query below to grab all records that have a `SubCategoryName == subCatName` and i want to return all of there `ProductID`'s as a list of `ints`. Problem is when my code runs it is only returning 1 int(record) instead of all. How can i make it return all of the records that have that subCatName? Its returning a count = 1 with a capacity of 4. So it is a `int[4]` but only the first [0] is = to a actual product ID the rest returning zero?

```
   public List<int> GetPRodSubCats(string subCatName)
    {
        var _db = new ProductContext();

        if (subCatName != null)
        {
            var  query = _db.ProductSubCat
                            .Where(x => x.SubCategory.SubCategoryName == subCatName)
                            .Select(p => p.ProductID);

            return query.ToList<int>();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. Are you 100% sure your query doesn't just return 1 row?

Comment: You sure you have more than one result to return anyway? Try using Linqpad to test things out (http://www.linqpad.net/)

Comment: Make sure that your database has more than one record for that subcategory :)

Comment: Maybe you are only looking at the first one.

Comment: @DanielKelley I looked in the Database and there is multi records that  fit my params. It is like it is only grabbing the first record.

Comment: It was right. It turns out to that it was another method causing the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Daniel already has mentioned, the code should work. But maybe you are expecting that it's case-insensitive or ignores white-spaces. So this is more tolerant:

```
subCatName = subCatName.Trim();
List<int> productIDs = _db.ProductSubCat
     .Where(x => String.Equals(x.SubCategory.SubCategoryName.Trim(), subCatName, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
     .Select(p => p.ProductID)
     .ToList();
```

Comment: The class name "Context" and the variable name "_db" indicates that he is using Entity Framework. In this case your code won't work because it can't be translated to an SQL statement.

Comment: @JustAnotherUserYouMayKnow: Overlooked it somehow. `String.Equals` on the other hand should work as this answer suggests: http://stackoverflow.com/a/841342/284240

Comment: This will result in an ArgumentException "Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Boolean Equals(System.String, System.String, System.StringComparison)'" when enumerating the query. Stans answer works, also when you add an ".Trim()" before or after the ".ToLower()". This was tested with EntityFramework 4. The stackoverflow answer you linked refers to linq-to-sql, not linq-to-entities. It all depends on what framework he is actually using. ;-)

Answer (score 2):

This seems more like an expected behavior here. How do you know you don't only have 1 record that satisfies the `Where` predicate.

Your code is correct, however you might want to normalize your comparison.

`x => x.SubCategory.SubCategoryName == subCatName`

to use a specific case for instance:

`x => x.SubCategory.SubCategoryName.ToLower() == subCatName.ToLower()`

you might also consider a Trim.