# Case sensitive in linq Query

Tags: c#, linq

this code use Authentication person for login ,my problem is in password for example if

pass=AAaa and we enter aaaa  login in system ,what to do for case sensitive in search?

```
Inspector inspector = context.Inspectors.Where(i => i.InspectorUserName == userName

                && i.InspectorPssWord == passWord).FirstOrDefault();
```

thanks

Comment: Did you try it? because I would say this is already checking case sensitive. PS: shouldn't you encrypt the passwords and compare the hashes instead?

Comment: this question is dublicated. original question and answer is  [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql

Comment: The problem is most likely your DB is doing a case-insensitive search. If you're using SQL Server, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/3054977/310574 for making that field case-sensitive.

Comment: Is this a L2S or EF scenario?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Linq (and C# for that matter) **already does case sensitive checks**, so you don't have to modify your code to include that.

On another note though, you should **really** hash those passwords :)