# LINQ To SQL Contains Case Sensitive Searching

Tags: c#, linq, case-sensitive

When I use below query, it gets result perfectly. But it is case-sensitive. Here is my codes:

```
    IQueryable<article> results;
    if (rrbAuthor.IsChecked)
        results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid where a.author.Contains(textBox1.Text) select a).Distinct();
    else if (rrbKeywords.IsChecked)
        results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid where k.word.Contains(textBox1.Text) select a).Distinct();
    else
        results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid where a.title.Contains(textBox1.Text) select a).Distinct();

    ListArticles(results, 1);
```

How can I manage to get results in in-sensitive case?

Comment: @HabipOĞUZtry following `k.word.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower())`

Comment: @tchelidze Ok! Sorry my for my coriosity. Is it according to the rules?

Comment: @HabipOĞUZ which rules do you have in account ?

Comment: Your question has already been [asked (and answered)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841226/case-insensitive-string-compare-in-linq-to-sql) before...

Comment: @tchelidze Using `ToLower()` both two side sounds plaster over the wound.

Comment: @HabipOĞUZ Ok, then you can use  comparison like this `string1.Equals(string2,  StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can transform string into lower case, using `ToLower()` method and then do comparison 
You can also use [null propagation](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/900017/Null-Propagation-Operator-A-New-Feature-of-Csharp) in oder to avoid `NullReference` Exception in case some of the `stirngs` is null.

Try following

```
  IQueryable<article> results;
  if (rrbAuthor.IsChecked)
    results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid
               where a.author?.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text?.ToLower()) == true
               select a).Distinct();
  else if (rrbKeywords.IsChecked)
    results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid
               where k.word?.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text?.ToLower()) == true
               select a).Distinct();
  else
    results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid
               where a.title?.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text?.ToLower()) == true
               select a).Distinct();
  ListArticles(results, 1);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .ToUpper() or .ToLower() two sides:

```
    results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid 
where a.author.ToUpper().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToUpper()) select a).Distinct();
```

Or

```
    results = (from a in _db.articles join k in _db.keywords on a.id equals k.aid 
where a.author.ToLower().Contains(textBox1.Text.ToLower()) select a).Distinct();
```