# Linq selecting object from relational list of object by search keyword

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

> I want to get the Principal of School using a search keyword. Schools
>   can have list of users from which one is of a principal role.
>
> Now my problem is I am implementing an auto search that takes a
>   keyword and searches on the basis for School Name, Code, and principal
>   name.

Code :

```
 public class School : AuditableDataEntity<int>
    {
        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(150)]
        public string Code { get; set; }

        public District District { get; set; }

        public ICollection<UserProfile> Users { get; set; }


    }

public class UserProfile : AuditableDataEntity<Guid>
    {

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string LastName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [MaxLength(200)]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string PhoneWork { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(20)]
        public int PhoneWorkExt { get; set; }

        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string PhoneMobile { get; set; }       

        public UserLevel UserLevel { get; set; }

        public UserRole UserRole { get; set; }

        public UserDesignation UserDesignation { get; set; }

        public School School { get; set; }
        public int? SchoolId { get; set; }

        public string FullName => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    }

Task<Response<IEnumerable<SchooSearchDTO>>> ISchoolQueryService.GetSchoolAutoCompleteData(string searchKeyword)
        {
            return _schoolQueryRepository.WithRelatedEntities().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchKeyword)
            ||x.Code.Contains(searchKeyword)
            || x.Users.FirstOrDefault(y => y.DataEntityState == DataEntityState.Published && y.UserDesignation == UserDesignation.Principal).FullName.Contains(searchKeyword)).OrderBy(u => u.Name).Select(z => new SchooSearchDTO
            {
                PrincipalName = z.Name,
                CDSCode = z.Code

            }).ToResponseListAsync();
        }
```

**Error :**

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet
>       .Where(s => s.Name.Contains(__searchKeyword_0) || s.CDSCode.Contains(__searchKeyword_0) || DbSet
>           .Where(u => EF.Property>(s, "Id") != null && EF.Property>(s, "Id") == EF.Property>(u,
>   "SchoolId"))
>           .Where(u => (int)u.DataEntityState == 1 && (int)u.UserDesignation == 1)
>           .Select(u => u.FullName)
>           .FirstOrDefault().Contains(__searchKeyword_0))' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated,
>   or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to
>   either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or
>   ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for
>   more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here that EF can not translate this into SQL.

```
x.Users.FirstOrDefault(y => y.DataEntityState == DataEntityState.Published && y.UserDesignation == UserDesignation.Principal).FullName.Contains(searchKeyword)
```

So try to use `Any` instead of selecting user with `FirstOrDefault` in LINQ, so that EF be able to translate this into SQL.

```
Task<Response<IEnumerable<SchooSearchDTO>>> ISchoolQueryService.GetSchoolAutoCompleteData(string searchKeyword)
{
    return _schoolQueryRepository.WithRelatedEntities().Where(x => x.Name.Contains(searchKeyword)
        ||x.Code.Contains(searchKeyword)
        || x.Users.Any(y => y.DataEntityState == DataEntityState.Published && y.UserDesignation == UserDesignation.Principal && y.FirstName.Contains(searchKeyword))
    ).OrderBy(u => u.Name).Select(z => new SchooSearchDTO
    {
        PrincipalName = z.Name,
        CDSCode = z.Code

    }).ToResponseListAsync();
}
```

See: [The LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872910/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally)

Edit:

You also need to use `FirstName` since `FullName` is property that you don't have in SQL.

Comment: Same error with any need to look for another way around.

Comment: It worked by a change to && y.FirstName.Contains(searchKeyword) problem was with FullName so it worked by changing to Any and changing FullName to FirstName.

Comment: Yes good point, I forgot to mentioned that.. I have updated my answer.