# where linq with trim replace character and ignore case

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I'm using EF and i would like to make a search on field Name, this search must ignore character - and space and the case

on my table i have

```
id Name
1  Jean -philippe
```

when i'm make the search on my resqust sometime i have `jeanphilippe`, some times `jean philippe`

I need to match this with the record on db like:

```
await repository.FindAsync(m=>m.Name.ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty).Trim()==request.Name.ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty).Trim())

 public async Task<User> FindAsync(Expression<Func<User, bool>> match)
        {
            return await _databaseContext.user.FirstOrDefaultAsync(match).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
```

but i have EF error

```
The LINQ expression 'DbSet<user> where (.....) could not be translated.
```

How can i resolve this please?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The LINQ expression could not be translated and will be evaluated locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872910/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally)

Comment: Are you sure that "request.Name" has a value? Also another issue is that "Trim" only removes spaces from the beginning and the end of a string, so you will need to do a "replace" on those as well, that doesn't explain the error message though.

Comment: yes has a value

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: Try changing `Expression<Func<User, bool>> match` to `Func<User, bool> match`

Comment: I'm using sqlserver 2016

Comment: You probably don't need the `ToLower` because SQL Server defaults to a collation that is case insensitive.  For the rest you need to determine the correct functions to use that will translate based on your version of EF.

Comment: All used functions a listed as [supported](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/sql-server/functions#string-functions) by EF For SQL Server. Try moving `request.Name.ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty).Trim()` to outside variable and "play" with the `m.Name.ToLower().Replace("-", string.Empty).Trim()` part, to see what fails to be translated (remove some of function calls, change `string.Empty` to `""` and so on).

Comment: Which version of EF Core do you use? in EF Core 5 your query works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Everything will be done on the server side, so if the search is case-sensitive or not, will be decided by the database collation.

Maybe to ignore such things you should split up your search term be all whitespaces and send a like statement for each one and AND all of them. Maybe something like this sketch:

```
var name = "Foo -Bar";
var cleanedName = name
    //.Replace(".", string.Empty)  // Maybe other characters to remove before search
    .Replace("-", string.Empty);

var elements = cleanedName.Split();
IQueryable<Foo> query = respository.Foo;

foreach (var element in elements)
{
    query = query.Where(foo => EF.Functions.Like(foo.Name, $"%{element}%"));
}

var results = await query.ToListAsync();
```

Be aware, that this is only a *sketch*. Especially simply using the `element` directly can produce false outcomes, if the search term entered by the user contains characters, that are interpreted by the `LIKE` function of the database like `%`, `_`, `[` or `]` (probably more).

Also be aware that doing a bunch of `LIKE` statements on a table maybe containing a lot of rows containing maybe a lot of text could lead to a HUGE processing time for the SQL database. Don't forget to measure the performance and maybe check for some full text indices on the server side to improve performance if needed.