# LINQ Queryable.Take() with range parameter could not be translated

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

With EF Core 7.0, when I query data with basic pagination:

```
var data = (from item in _db.items
            where... // filtering
            orderby.... // ordering
            select item)


var dataToSend = await data.Skip(x).Take(Y).ToListAsync();
```

Everything works as expected.

However, when I try using Queryable.Take(x..y) "with the range parameter", for example:

```
var from = x;
var to = y;

var dataToSend = await data.Take(from..to).ToListAsync();
```

I receive an error that the LINQ expression could not be translated.

Why isn't this working?

Comment: Check the most up votes answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57872910/the-linq-expression-could-not-be-translated-and-will-be-evaluated-locally

Comment: *Why isn't this working?* -- Just because there's no supported SQL translation for all LINQ-to-objects methods.

Comment: Yup, as @Gert (HNY!) said. The question is why Net Core BCL team is adding new methods to the interface if they are supported only in LINQ to Objects (which normally is not used with `IQueryable`), thus just opening additional confusion. Same for new types like `DateOnly` and `TimeOnly` - nice, but not supported even with their ADO.Net driver :(

Comment: @Ivan (same to you!) Maybe because they're optimistic in what third-party query providers dare to implement. I only wish the [docs on supported LINQ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities) would be kept up-to-date and were prominently present in the EF docs, preferably as a caption [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/).

Comment: Exactly! In documentation it is not possible to make a distinction between what can and can't be translated to SQL. As the `.Skip(x).Take(y)` is translatable I expected the .`Take(x..y)` to be translatable as well (both do the same with different syntax). A heads-up note in the documentation and maybe in the IDE will be very useful!

Comment: @Damascus what about `source.Skip(x).Take(y - x + 1);` or use `SkipWhile` `TakeWhile` ?

Comment: @viveknuna, the usual `.Skip(x).Take(y)` works. But my question was about the newer shorter syntax `.Take(Range)` which has no SQL translation support yet as mentioned in the accepted answer. I thought this would be supported by maybe dealing with `.Take(Range)` as a `.Skip(x).Take(y)` before translation. It may be not that simple; and the EF Core team certainly has more insight about why it isn't supported yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why isn't this working?

.NET 6 has introduced [several new LINQ methods (and overloads to existing ones)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/additional-linq-queryable-method-overloads) which require their support to be implemented in every [LINQ provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/mattwar/linq-building-an-iqueryable-provider-part-i) otherwise they will not work correctly. ATM EF Core team is considering/working on supporting them - you can track [this summary issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/25570) or [this one](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/24479), particularly covering `Take(Range)` (and `ElementAt(Index)`).

Answer (score 0):

The `Take` method in LINQ expects an integer argument that represents the number of elements to take.

It also can accept a Range parameter, in the form of a `Range` object.

A small example:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[] numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };

            var result = numbers.AsQueryable().Take(2..4).ToList();

            Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", result));
        }
    }
}
```

Try adding the `AsQueryable()` before the `Take()` method.

The `Take` method in LINQ is equivalent to the SQL `SELECT TOP` clause, which also expects a single integer argument.

Comment: Why guess when you can check - here is [`Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.take?view=net-7.0#system-linq-queryable-take-1(system-linq-iqueryable((-0))-system-range)) accepting `Range`.

Comment: _"The Take method in LINQ is equivalent to the SQL SELECT TOP clause"_ - that is true for SQL Server, but not all databases support `TOP` AFAIK.

Comment: @GuruStron You are correct, It does have support. Let me modify my answer.

Comment: @Imesashvili_Irakli `data` in my example is already an `IQueryable`

Comment: @Damascus try to use 2 dots instead of 3 `from...to`

Comment: @Imesashvili_Irakli `Range`' syntax uses two dots only, I fixed the typo in my question